# Angular 4: Validating a model (not a form)?

Tags: angular, validation

I'm building an Angular 4 mobile app (with Ionic 2). A shared service holds a `Visit` object, which the user can edit. The main page of the app looks like this:

```
* Section 1: Customer Details (Complete)
* Section 2: Property Info (Incomplete)
* Section 3: Audit Results (Incomplete)

[Submit Visit]
```

Tapping each section takes the user to a separate page, where they can edit that section of the `Visit`. *The user can save each section even if it's invalid or incomplete.* On the main page, each section changes from "(Incomplete)" to "(Complete)" when all required information in that section is present and valid. When all sections are valid, the "Submit Visit" button becomes enabled.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- On the section pages, I'd like to display form validation messages as usual (using a `FormGroup`), so the user can easily see which fields still need attention.
- **Here's where things get tricky:** on the main page, I need some way to test the validity of each section of the Visit object. But `FormGroup` validates forms, and the `Visit` object (obviously) is not a form. So, I'm not sure how to reuse the `FormGroups` to validate the `Visit` directly. (I'm guessing this isn't a great idea anyway, and it may not even be possible.)

I *could* implement my validation twice: as a set of `FormGroups` (to validate each section's form), and as a custom `VisitValidatorService` (to validate the `Visit` object directly). However, this obviously isn't ideal - I'd be duplicating code, and it'd be fiddly to keep the two sets of validation in sync.

Ideas that I've thought of:

1. As the user saves each section, set a flag (*e.g.*, `isSection1Valid = true`) on the `Visit` object. This won't work for me, because when the `Visit` is first loaded into the app (via a JSON API), some sections might already be valid. So I would still need some way to check each section's validity without involving an actual form.

*or,*

2. Forget about using `FormGroup` altogether. Build my `VisitValidatorService` so that it can validate both raw `Visit` object *and* form models. Finally, wire up my section controllers to call this service whenever a form control changes, and stash any returned errors in a public `errors` object that can then be displayed in the template.

   This seems viable, but...complicated.

Is there a better approach? Or am I trying to do something that Angular 4 just doesn't handle comfortably?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do the validation work twice, then one option can be that the individual forms will do that for you.
Your Visit object is made of three different objects which can all have an additional property "isValid".

Each time a form is posted (meaning the form is valid), you update the property isValid to True.
Then your main page can have its own isValid flag which is the product of the three others.
In order for that to work, you can either Get the latest Visit Object from the server to resolve the new state of the overall status.

Or Assume isValid is true after each successful POST for each of the sub elements of Visit object.

Comment: This solution was already proposed (and rejected) in my question – see bullet point 1, toward the bottom. I need an approach to validation which (1) can be used to validate a JavaScript object *or* a form model, and (2) doesn't *rely* on a form.

Comment: I understand your concern. Here are the possible scenarios : 1- The user is using this page for the very first time to which case all sections are invalid by default. 2-User enters one of the sections and edit them. when they do, you can save/persist the state of each sections independently in the server. 3 The user comes back to this page another time, you then get the latest state of each section from the server to validate the whole page.